# Adding objects to custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Trying to use a custom cell which a label and two buttons.
I managed to create a subclass for custom cell and I need to show them in the cell as well. This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

var fruits = ["Orange", "Apple", "Banana"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.rowHeight = 80

    self.tableView.register(tableDetailsVCTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

@objc func downloadPressed() {
    print("Download Button Presses")
}

@objc func previewPressed() {
    print("Preview Button Pressed")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruits.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! tableDetailsVCTableViewCell
    cell.lable?.text = fruits[indexPath.row]
    cell.dlB?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(downloadPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.pvB?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(previewPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
}
```

I run the app but nothing shows up. No text in the label nor any buttons

Comment: As you are using storyboard, try commenting this line out `self.tableView.register(tableDetailsVCTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or UITableViewCell xib?

Comment: do you mean you see cells but no labels and buttons or you don't see cell at all?

Comment: @Imad a storyboard

Comment: @VahidGR Then no need to registerCell in viewDidLoad, Just make sure that you're using same Table view cell identifier.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq cells are there but they are empty. I tried to pass the fruits in the cells directly and it worked but I need them in the "lable" label

Comment: @Imad omg I'm so silly it worked :D sorry for bothering

Comment: @VahidGR Happy Coding :-) Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you're using storyboard for designing the Custom TableViewCell then no need to register cell, just remove this line of code from `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.register(tableDetailsVCTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

`viewDidLoad` looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.rowHeight = 80
}
```